# Stack overflow when inheriting from base (master) template

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, flask-admin

I want to extend [access_control](https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/doc/templates.rst#jinja2--flask-admin) block to add authentication menu links. I don't want to overwrite whole master.html template, so I created templates/admin/mymaster.html file with the following contents:

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}
{% block access_control %}
    {{ super() }}
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <...>
        </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Now I've got:
[image]
What am I doing wrong?
Lately, I've overridden admin/index.html same way:

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}
{% block body %}
  <p>Here I'm going to display some data.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

and it works well.

MCVE:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
from flask.ext.admin.base import MenuLink, Admin, BaseView, expose

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'

flaskadmin = admin.Admin(name='Flasky', template_mode='bootstrap3', 
                   base_template='admin/mymaster.html')

flaskadmin.init_app(app)

# Start app
app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: there shouldn't the parent `()`, as in django template the method is already callable. Have you tried using just `{{ block.super }}`?

Comment: in jinga2 there should be super() if want to extend block, anyway it doesn't matter, super plays no role since it is inheritance problem.

Comment: well you should really mention jinja2 in your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: well fair enough once I click the link it's quite obvious it's flask + jinja2. I haven't used *flask-admin* before so hope you get someone with experience to help

Comment: you should show the full traceback. it would be helpful if you post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because what is posted does not reproduce the issue.

Comment: that code doesn't reproduce the issue ... WTForms==2.1, Flask-Admin==1.4.0. also there is an error. should `admin.Admin` be `Admin` in the `flaskadmin` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask-admin documentation is a bit confusing, because it tells you:

> You can also override the master template, but then you need to pass
>   your own template name to the Admin constructor:
>
> `admin = Admin(app, base_template='my_master.html')`

Flask-admin uses proxy template, named master.html and contained just one following line:

```
{% extends admin_base_template %}
```

When we pass base_template to our Admin constructor, admin_base_template variable becomes overridden to our new my_master/my_base template, so we can't just inherit from it, otherwise it would cause cycling inheriting and stack overflow. Instead of inheriting from admin/master, we just should inherit admin/base.html. This way, my solution becomes:

```
<-- admin/mymaster.html -->
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
{% block access_control %}
    {{ super() }}
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <...>
        </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Now you just inherit all your templates from admin/master.html (as before), because it points at new base/mymaster

Comment: "we just should inherit admin/base.html." this is what I told you. "you override admin/base.html not admin/master.html".

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with this line, which is meant to create a custom base template.

```
flaskadmin = admin.Admin(name='Flasky', template_mode='bootstrap3', 
                   base_template='admin/mymaster.html')
```

See: https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/blob/master/flask_admin/base.py#L490-L491

> ```
> :param base_template:
>     Override base HTML template for all static views.
>     Defaults to `admin/base.html`.
> ```

It seems to me that this is not what you want to do. If you change the application code as below, the recursion problem does not happen.

```
flaskadmin = Admin(name='Flasky')
```

From what I can tell if you want to override the base template you override *admin/base.html* not *admin/master.html*.

For example:

```
.
├── app.py
└── templates
    └── admin
        ├── mybase.html
        └── mymaster.html
```

*app.py*:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.admin.base import Admin

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'

flaskadmin = Admin(name='Flasky', base_template='admin/mybase.html')
flaskadmin.init_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*templates/admin/mybase.html*:

```
{% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
```

*templates/admin/mymaster.html*:

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}
{% block access_control %}
    {{ super() }}
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
       <li>One</li>
       <li>Two</li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think Flask-admin documentation is a bit confusing:
`You can also override the **master** template, but then you need to pass your own template name to the Admin constructor:`

admin = Admin(app, base_template='my_master.html')

https://github.com/mrjoes/flask-admin/blob/master/doc/templates.rst#customizing-templates